# discord.utils.get Voice clients are None, even if bot is connected to a voice channel. discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have the problem, that when i use discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild) it is returning None, even when it's connected. I wanna let the bot reconnect to a voice channel,  because the bot is getting kicked after around 3-4 hours. I tried to let it reconnect to the channel using a file which contains the name of the channel to reconnect to.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import os
import nacl
from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.command(aliases=['shreksophone'])
async def shrek(ctx, *, join_channel: str=None):
  voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  global guild_for_reconnect, guild_for_reconnect_voice_channels
  guild_for_reconnect = str(ctx.guild)
  guild_for_reconnect_voice_channels = ctx.guild.voice_channels
  guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
  author_id = str(ctx.author.id)
  async def shrek_repeat(ctx):
    f = open('shrek_counter', 'r+')
    counter = f.read()
    new_counter = int(counter) + 1
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(str(new_counter))
    f.close()
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('songs/1 hour of shreksophone.m4a'), after=lambda e: asyncio.run(shrek_repeat(ctx)))
  if not os.path.exists(guild_id):
    f = open(guild_id, 'w')
    f.write(author_id)
    f.close()
  f = open(guild_id, 'r')
  session_author = f.read()
  f.close()
  if session_author == author_id:
    if voice is None:
      if join_channel is None:
        if ctx.author.voice:
          channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
          await channel.connect()
          await ctx.send('Playing shreksophone now in "' + channel.name + '" repeatedly.')
          print('Playing shreksophone now repeatedly in ' + ctx.guild.name + '.')
          voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
          voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('songs/1 hour of shreksophone.m4a'), after=lambda e: asyncio.run(shrek_repeat(ctx)))
          f = open(guild_for_reconnect + ' channel', 'w')
          f.write(str(channel))
          f.close()
          bot.loop.create_task(voice_reconnect())
        else:
          await ctx.send('You have to be in a voice channel, if you want me to play shreksophone.')
          print('User is not in a voice channel.')
      else:
        channel = get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=join_channel)
        channel_exist = get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=join_channel)
        while channel_exist is None:# the code here just continues with other possibilities 


async def voice_reconnect():
  while True:
    if os.path.exists(guild_for_reconnect + ' channel'):
      voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild_for_reconnect)
      f = open(guild_for_reconnect + ' channel', 'r')
      channel = f.read()
      f.close()
      channel_to_reconnect = get(guild_for_reconnect_voice_channels, name=channel)
      if voice is None:# so even if the bot is connected it still returns None
        await channel_to_reconnect.connect()
      if voice.channel.name is not str(channel_to_reconnect):
        await voice.move_to(channel_to_reconnect)
      await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
```